# What does the word 'rebound' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a medical context I saw:

> On examination - bilateral axillary lymphadenopathy up to 2 cm and diffuse abdominal tenderness without **rebound**.

What does the word 'rebound' mean in this context?
I found this meaning ([rebound effect - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebound_effect)) that I know, but it does not go together with this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia *abdominal examination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_examination)

> Palpation
> Rebound: pain on release.

Also known as *rebound tenderness* :
[Wikipedia *Blumberg sign*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blumberg_sign)

> Blumberg's sign (also referred to as **rebound tenderness** or the Shyotkin–Blumberg sign) is a clinical sign in which there is pain upon removal of pressure rather than application of pressure to the abdomen. (The latter is referred to simply as abdominal tenderness.) It is indicative of peritonitis. It was named after German surgeon Jacob Moritz Blumberg

[emphasis added]

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jack O'Flaherty's excellent answer, rebound tenderness is classically felt in a different location from the examiner's pressure.

For example, when the examiner's pressure is released from the left lower quadrant of the abdomen, pain is often perceived in the right lower quadrant in the case of appendicitis.